# Making two storyboards for iOS (iPhone and iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to make only one application and inside of it make two storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad? I don't like the idea of running the app on iPad and clicking the 2x button.

My idea was to create two storyboards and have a beginning class that would check if the device you are using is an iPhone or an iPad and then redirect to the according storyboard after. I think it is a good idea cause the code is the same.

Comment: Yes. This is how Universal Apps work with Storyboards by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create two different storyboards and name them so they are easily specified which is which. Then click on the file that allows you to change settings for your actual app. and change the build to `universal`, then specify which storyboard you want to use!

there is a storyboard setting for iphone and ipad

iPhone

[image]

iPad

[image]

Make sure the names of the storyboards are correctly set though

Answer (score 4):

Even if you already made an app non universal, just change it to universal (target-->summary), then create a new ipad story board and make sure under target-->summary that the main iphone storyboard and main ipad storyboard are set to the right storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try creating new Universarl XCode project? If you create Universal project, there will be two Storyboards(One for iPhone and another one for iPad) created by default. i think.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this in a project recently...  so first you should navigate to your projects target then click the summary button in the top bar you will then see a bar that says "iOS Application Target" in there you will see a drop down menu with a title that says Devices select the universal option.  Now add a storyboard for the iPad.  Now go back to the projects target and scroll down to the "iPad Deployment Info" section and set your new storyboard as the main storyboard in the text field here you can also add the iPad icon and launch images.  Now you are set up for creating a universal app!

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, just do the app in `universal` and then go to the target and then info and then add the main `storyborad` file base name (iPad) then build and run when iPhone is run to its show iPhone and when iPad run so show as iPad.