# how to give two sizes(for iPhone and iPad ) for UIView using auto layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

how to give sizes for view(height or width) for a iPhone and iPad separately using auto layout via interface builder ?

Comment: Apple suggests you to use 2 storyboards. One for iPhone, one for iPad

Comment: Use two storyboards if you are using storyboard. and use two xibs if you are using xib. for iPhone and iPad individual

Comment: @Raptor after next iPhone release (if its different size), we have to use 3 storyboards or 3 xibs, then what the point of auto layout ?

Comment: Defenetly two storyboards, it's about different devices iPhone and iPad not about iPhone releases

Comment: in Xcode 4 "summery" tab (under "targets") there exist iPhone/ iPad deployment info. but in Xcode 5 doesn't have that kind of option. prior to Xcode 5 i thinks yours suggestion right, but under Xcode 5 ..?..
you can get more info via this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614043/making-two-storyboards-for-ios-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Max 2 storyboards only (iPhone & iPad). There is difference in retina resolution ( `@2x`, `@3x` only). You can select your main Storyboard name in Project setting. Make sure you select Universal app

Comment: hi @Raptor how can i find this thing in Project settings, can you guide me, I'm using Xcode 5

Comment: click your project on your left, select Targets > General > Devices

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but for everyone coming here, the answer is: You don't. If the reason wasn't very clear back in 2014 when this question was asked, it **is** very clear since iOS 9 and the introduction of Split View and Slide Over.

To be a bit more concrete:

- Don't rely on separate storyboards or `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom`. This tells you if you are on an iPhone or iPad, but since an app can now be in split view, it doesn't give you ANY information about available screen real estate
- Don't rely on `UIScreen.main.bounds` - if an app is in split view, the screen bounds might not equal your app's size, so this information is useless for layout decisions
- Don't blindly rely on `self.view.bounds` in your view controller. If the user moves the app into split view, the size of your view might change at any time. You CAN use this if you're monitoring the bounds (e.g. by overriding `bounds` and using `didSet`), but I would argue there is almost always a better way, and this doesn't help you if you are not in a view controller.

Apple [recommends using size classes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/). While this does seem a bit limiting at first and takes some getting used to, almost all layout decisions these days can be solved using size classes and proper auto layout. The great thing about size classes is that, if the size class changes, for example because an app moves into split view, the system will automatically take care of removing the auto layout constraints of old size class and adding the appropriate ones for the new size class.